# Chrome Mobile: (Angular) Input scroll to end on focus

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, mobile-chrome

pre: I have an Angular2 application (PWA) that is only used on two different android devices inside our facilites, and only chrome is supported, so no worries about compatibilties.
These devices are equipped with barcode scanner

I have a problem where I have a form that looks like this

[image: default look of the form]

The first input "Artikelnummer" is autofocused, but the keyboard is not opend as the user will use the barcode scanner to input this field.
Then the "Menge"(Quantity) input is focused so that they can input the data via keyboard.
I want the "Artikelnummer" to stay visible (for the user to check if they scanned the correct barcode, as multiple can be fairly close to each other)
Like this:

[image: old behavior with all inputs visible]

I focus the element via

```
  private focus(element: HTMLInputElement) {
    element.focus();
    this.scrollIntoVieW(element);
  }

  private scrollIntoVieW(element: HTMLInputElement) {
    element.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'end',
    });
  }
```

For the past few month, we had no problem, but suddenly it stopped working and I cant figure out why or how to re-create the old behavior.
The "Menge" input scrolls into the middle of the screen, scrolling the Artikelnummer out.

[image: after focusswitch]

Chrome Android does no support `focus({preventScroll: true})` so that is not an option.